# Applying tint on AppCompatImageView using selector in old API levels

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-appcompat, backwards-compatibility

I have the following image selector.

### label_icon_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_sort_by_alpha_white_24dp"
            app:tint="@color/colorPrimaryLight" />
    </item>

    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_sort_by_alpha_white_24dp"
            app:tint="@color/greyIconColorLight" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

and I use it in the following way.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:paddingStart="24dp"
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/label_icon_selector" />
```

The tinting effect is workable in API 26.

However, the tinting effect is not workable in old API (API 15)

I thought by having `app:tint`, and using `AppCompatImageView`, will enable me to achieve backward compatible?

May I know what step I had missed out?

Comment: Please let me know if specifying tintMode worked, so that I can improve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying tintMode too.

If it won't work, use Color state list instead.

Here is a demo.

selector_color_icon.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:color="@color/@colorPrimaryLight" />
     <item android:state_pressed="false"
           android:color="@color/greyIconColorLight" />
 </selector>
```

Usage:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    ....
    app:tint="@color/selector_color_icon"
    ....
/>
```

Comment: Oh that's weird. Are you sure it is working on newer versions? It might be a silly issue like missing to make the imageview clickable or putting the same color for both state. Also make sure it is AppCompatActivity.